# Customize selection controls in QML TextArea on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

When I use the TextArea from Qt Quick Controls on Android (in an Qt QML app), I can select text by long clicking on it and I get these controls for the selection:

[image: Selection controls on Nexus 6P]

Can I somehow customize on how they look?
I can find nothing in [TextAreaStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textareastyle.html#selectionColor-prop).

Comment: Private stuff, see [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Android/TextAreaStyle.qml#n72).